# Microsoft SQL server management studio : insert label in SQL query results

Tags: sql-server, query

I'm working with SQL server, using Microsoft SQL Management Studio.

I'm writing quite some SQL queries, one after the other.
This causes a list of results, which are quite difficult to distinguish, as you can see (I have quite some tables, having `Id` as first column):

[image]

My queries look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customer.[dbo].TableName
WHERE ...
```

Is it possible to add a label to the SQL queries' results?
Something like:

[image]

If the labels equal the table name, that's ok too.

Does anybody know how to do this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I am unaware of a way to add custom labels to result pane. You can add a column to the query to help identify

```
    SELECT 'label1',*
FROM Customer.[dbo].TableName
WHERE ...
```

Comment: Thanks. It's a start, but it's quite ugly. Hopefully something better will come up :-)